# Multiple OR and AND conditions with Elasticsearch php

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

I would like to achieve the following query with ElasticSearch :

product_shipper = 1 AND ((product_type = product and price>0) OR (product_type = product_variation and price=0))

I've built the following query but it doesn't work, sending me an empty result :

```
              "query"=> [
                  "bool"=> [
                     "must"=> [
                        [
                           "bool"=> [
                              "should" => [
                                    "bool"=> [
                                        "must"=> [
                                            [ "match" => [ "product_type" => "product" ] ],
                                            [ 
                                                'range'=>['price'=>['gt'=>0]]
                                            ],
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                     "bool"=> [
                                        "must"=> [
                                            [ "match" => [ "product_type" => "product_variation" ] ],
                                            [ "match" => [ "price" => 0 ] ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                              ]
                           ]
                        ],
                        [ 'match' => [ 'product_shipper' => $shipper ] ],
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a tiny issue in my syntax at the should clause level, here is the working code example, hope it helps a lot of people starting with Elasticsearch.

```
"query"=> [
"bool"=> [
    "must"=> [
        [
            "bool"=> [
                "should" => [
                    [
                        "bool"=> [
                            "must"=> [
                                [ "match" => [ "product_type" => "product" ] ],
                                [ "range"=>['price'=>['gt'=>0]]],
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        "bool"=> [
                            "must"=> [
                                [ "match" => [ "product_type" => "product_variation" ] ],
                                ['range'=>['price'=>['lte'=>0]]]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'match' => [ 'product_shipper' => $shipper ]
        ],
    ]
]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, helped me with pretty much the same problem!